# cursor.getCount() return 0 while table is not empty

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I have a table in SQLite that hold only one entry - the version number of my database.
currently using DB Browser for SQLite I can see that the table has one row.

but when I run the following code, it shows that cursor.getCount() is 0
WHY??

```
private boolean checkVersion(DBmanipulation currentDB) {
    //returning value
    boolean newerVersionExist = false;

    //Get SQLiteVersion
    String currentQuery = "SELECT " + KEY_VERSION + " FROM " + TABLE_VERSION;
    Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(currentQuery, null);

    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        //there is something in the table
        //Check if the current version is older
        int currentVersion = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("version_number"));
        System.out.println("RESULTzz Current version is:" + currentVersion);

        int remoteVersion = currentDB.getVersionNumber();
        System.out.println("RESULTzz Remote version is:" + remoteVersion);

        if (remoteVersion > currentVersion) {
            newerVersionExist = true;
        }
        return newerVersionExist;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried selecting all ? that means `SELECT * FROM TABLE_VERSION`, And still returns 0 ?

Comment: Tried means does it still return 0 ? If so try adding some dummy selectionargs instead of passing null if you are sure there is data.